# WebDriver find Element not containing attribute

Tags: java, extjs, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have following HTML

```
<button class="x-btn-text " style="position: relative; width: 69px;" type="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">OK</button>
<button class="x-btn-text" style="position: relative; width: 69px;" type="button" tabindex="0">OK</button>
```

The first button is disabled and the second button is enabled, since I want to click on the enabled button. Is there a way I could find the element, that doesn't have attribute `aria-disabled`?

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat, as they say. How many `buttons` have that `class`?

Comment: all buttons (Save, Ok, Cancel, New User etc) on the UI has the same `class`

Comment: since you seem to be back and forth with CSS, i can tell you're somewhat new to the web dev world.. when deciding wether to use css or xpath, you should [read this blog](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/) to see which one you think is best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExtJs case. Here you need determine if it's enabled or not by attribute `aria-disabled="false"` using `getAttribute("aria-disabled")` or XPath/CssSelector.

So Code Enthusiastic's logic should be correct, however ExtJS is always special on something.

```
List<WebElement> okButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[text() = 'OK']"));
for (WebElement okButton : okButtons) { 
    if (!okButton.getAttribute("aria-disabled").equals("false")) {
        okButton.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Or even easier, rule out the enabled one in your locator. (As you need to text here, so no suitable locator using CssSelector, only XPath)

```
WebElement enabledokButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text() = 'OK' and not(@aria-disabled = 'false')]"));
enabledokButton.click();
```

Comment: thanks a lot..this perfectly works. Good to know we can do so much using xpath expressions.

Comment: @aeinstein83: No worries. In this case you can't use CssSelector as you need to check the text. But in many other cases, CssSelectors are preferred than XPath, so you might want to learn some css selectors as well. :)

Comment: remove s in your second solution, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic: Thanks, as I copied the second one from the first one.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way I could find the element, that doesn't have attribute aria-disabled?

YES!
Utilize CSS!

Your selector to find a button without the `aria-disabled` attribute would be, `button:not([aria-disabled])`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button:not([aria-disabled])").click();
```

Comment: what happened to accepting mine?! hahaha.. and yes.. favor CSS

Comment: still not sure why CSS3 discontinued `:contains`... but yea, i know this. i was answering the specific question of "is there a way i could find the element.. without aria-disabled" `:)`

Comment: How to wait till the attribute disappears. i.e; in my case disabled attribute should disappear and then I want to click the button. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> okButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[text() = 'OK']"));
for (WebElement okButton : okButtons) { 
    if (okButton.isEnabled()) {
        okButton.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but I'm interested to know if `isEnabled` would *actually* be false due to the `aria-disabled` attribute since I don't think that's a standard attribute...if it isn't you'd have to explicitly check for it's presence.

Comment: I had tried that but as mentioned by Arran its not a standard attribute and it returns 'true'. so it doesnt work.