# how to collect a particular row id's in an table - webdriver using java collections

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Html code

```
<table id="tblRenewalsStatus" class="bor-bot" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr id="trVerifyPayment">
<tr id="trAssignAgent">
<tr id="trAssigned">
<tr id="trPayAgent" style="display: none;">
<tr id="trPaymentVerificationPending" style="display: none;">
<tr id="trInProgress" style="display: none;">
<tr id="trPayAgentCommission">
<tr id="trPaymentVerificationPendingCommission">
<tr id="trCompleted">
<tr id="trCancelled">
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to collect all the tr id's which don't have an style Attribute value in it,

Expected output,

"trVerifyPayment","trAssignAgent","trAssigned",trPayAgentCommission","trPaymentVerificationPendingCommission","trCompleted","trCancelled"

Comment: Make a list of all the `<tr>`, iterate over them and if they have a style attribute, remove them from the list and keep the others. Then you will have a list of `<tr>` without styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> id_elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='tblRenewalsStatus']//tr"));

    ArrayList<String> tr_id= new ArrayList<String>();
    for(WebElement ele : id_elements)
     {

        String style = ele.getAttribute("style");

        if(style==null||style=="")
        {
            String id=ele.getAttribute("id");
            tr_id.add(id);
        }
      }

    System.out.println(tr_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement RenewalTable = driver
                .findElement(By.id("tblRenewalsStatus"));
        List<WebElement> allRows = RenewalTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        ArrayList<String> enableRow = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (WebElement eachElement : allRows) {

            String style = eachElement.getAttribute("style");

            if (style.equals("")) {
                String id = eachElement.getAttribute("id");
                enableRow.add(id);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

problem about finding element without some attribute is solved here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18774549/2131257

and for find all element**s** is used method

```
driver.findElements(By.id("element_id"))
```

which return list of elements instead of

```
driver.findElement(By.id("element_id"))
```

which return only one element.

Hope it helps.